# Intsalling Linux on PowerEdge R410 via USB

Tags: ubuntu, linux, dell-poweredge, usb-boot

I’m hoping someone can help me with the following issue. I have a Dell PowerEdge R410 and basically the Optical Drive has failed when I have been given the server. I have installed 2 SATA drives and want to install Ubuntu 11.04; however, each time I have tried i.e. using bootable .iso on USB it failed. I assume it's failing as with a lot of releases they all look at the CD drive. Ubunutu has failed on installation with the error message unable to mount CD.

I have tried installing Microsoft Hyper-v and that also fails as during installation it asks for CD/DVD drivers. Tried embedding ISO's from various distro's (Linux and Windows) with drivers and that hasn't worked out either.

Does anyone have any idea on how I can get Ubuntu on this server? Should I look towards an old distro perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're following [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) (without success), here are options that don't involve a flash drive:

1. Attach a USB CD/DVD drive.
2. Open up the case, temporarily attach a regular SATA CD/DVD drive for installation.
3. Set the local DHCP server to enable PXE booting, install Ubuntu over the network.

Comment: Hi, I don't have a USB CD/DVD drive to hand and neither do I also have a regular SATA CD/DVD. Also I have taken the server out of the rack to get it up and running; therefore I cannot use PXE booting. I would have thought their was a version of linux that didn't look at, or attenpt to mount CD-ROM on install?

Comment: Given the existence of the USB install page I linked, and that it includes specific instructions on making a bootable USB using Windows, OS X, or Linux, I'd assume it's a distribution that won't attempt to mount a CD on install. There's also a USB troubleshooting page linked there. Given that we have zero details on what went wrong, my first inclination is to ask whether or not you made an actual bootable USB. If you can edit your question to include more details on what went wrong where, we can be more specific in what other steps you can take.

Answer (score 0):

The app at this link will download a USB bootable live distribution of Ubuntu (or many other distros if you like) and make the usb stick for you.

At no time will it ask for a cd.

If you are trying to take a straight Ubuntu CD or DVD image and not correctly setting up grub to load the right way you could have issues.

Use Yumi and it will do everything for you.

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/